# Dart analyzer loses track of app localizations when integration test runs

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-test

Has anyone else had an issue where the following occurs:

1. Trigger an integration test from the terminal in VSCode
2. This does a 'flutter pub get' before running the test
3. After the 'flutter pub get' the Dart analyzer seems to lose all knowledge of my app localizations
4. The integration test runs successfully

If I re-run 'flutter pub get' manually then the analyzer doesn't report any problems

[image: VSCode showing Dart analyzer losing knowledge about app localizations]